# How to add Windows Form Panel to Wpf TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been given a task and I'm stumped. I call an API in my WPF application, and it returns a Windows Forms Panel. My job is to display the panel inside my TabControl

At the moment, I'm doing the code in the CodeBehind in my WPF project, which looks like

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var panel = GetPanelFromApi();        

    this.MyTabControl.Items.Add(panel);//fail
}
```

The programs runs, no crash, but the Panel isn't shown in my TabControl, however, the TabControl does render as if there is 1 item (may it just isn't visible despite the panel's `visible` property set to true) !

If I update the code to

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Text = "Test";

    this.MyTabControl.Items.Add(tb);//yipee
}
```

Then it works as expected (I see the `TextBlock` control) so the issue is due to the Wpf not liking the Panel... I don't know how to fix it or what I should be looking at.

The XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
          <TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl"></TabControl>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: @FrebinFrancis, I have made the update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add windows forms controls you need to use [WindowsFormHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and this is how you can add it-

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host1 =
        new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

    System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel =
        new System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        {
            BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle};
            host1.Child = panel;

            ((this.MyTabControl.Items[0] as TabItem).Content as Grid).Children.Add(host1);
```

Also, If you are using TabControls and not using TabItems as its children, it's of no use to use TabControl (rather you can directly use Grid). But to add TabItems you should write you XAML like-

```
    <TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl" >
        <TabItem Header="TabItem 1">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem 2">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

In a probably similar scenario, we used a `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost` which was added to a WPF `Grid` inside a WPF `UserControl`. We got memory leak issues first when we added it directly in the XAML, but were able to resolve those by adding it dynamically in the code behind, something like

```
        winFormsHost = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost(); // WindowsFormsHost not added in Xaml in order to avoid Memory Leak
        namedWpfGrid.Children.Add(winFormsHost);

        dbiScheduler = new Dbi.WinControl.Schedule.dbiSchedule();
        dbiScheduler.FirstDraw += ... // lots of event-handler and property assignments following here
        winFormsHost.Child = dbiScheduler;
```

And by explicitly doing a `winFormHost.Dispose()` in a custom onClose() method of the UserControl

Answer (score 1):

I performed a test based on your code, and I added a Winform RichTextBox in the host, it displayed in the TabControl. Could you please try to add other controls in the Panel and then add the panel into TabItem? Please try to call [Control.CreateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrol.aspx) to create the control handle before adding it into the host.

Please remember to mark the replies as answers if they help.

Comment: I used  `var rtb = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();            rtb.Text = "Giddy";             this.MyTabControl.Items.Add(rtb);` and it doesn't display

Comment: you should refer this link it will helps you a lot   http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/tabcontrol/using-the-tabcontrol/ Dont forhet to upvote if you liked it